# Does Django not support Jinja manual whitespace control?

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to use the Jinja [manual whitespace control](https://tedboy.github.io/jinja2/templ6.html) inside a Django template

```
{% if condition -%}
  {{ my_variable }}
{% endif %}
```

and get `TemplateSyntaxError`

```
Could not parse the remainder: '-' from '-'
```

Django version is 3.2, Jinja 3.1.

Is this not supported? I see there is [django-whiteless](https://pypi.org/project/django-whiteless/) that might address this issue.

Comment: It's there on purpose, see first link, Jinja allows this for manual whitespace control.

Comment: Django default templating language is actually not Jinja: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/. `spaceless` is maybe what you are looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless

Comment: "Is this not supported?" - What does the Django manual say?